# What do vedas say about Eclipses

Tags: scripture, vedas, eclipse

I'd like to know how Vedas explain eclipses and what they say about eclipses.

How doe eclipses occur according to Vedas?

What do Vedas say about Eclipses in general?

Are eclipses considered inaspicious in Vedas?

Please cite the sources.

Comment: The linked question asked about all beliefs. All the beliefs related to the eclipses will be covered in the linked question. If there are new answers from various scriptures, then the answers are valid there. So, I voted to 'leave closed' in the reopen queue.

Comment: Vedas provides an altogether different answer on this issue, and this question is specific to Veda not to later developed Hindu mythology. Therefore the question put by Walley should not be put in to diplicate category.